# Tkinter: how to enlarge the button text without increasing the size of the button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from tkinter import *
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Scrivi lettera/spazio
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#STICK: lettera -
GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #STICK: lettera +
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Cancella lettera
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #TTS
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Spegnimento



x=0 #Variabile globale utile a determinare quale lettra mostrare
s="" #Stringa che serve a concatenare le lettere per  mostrare la parola


class mainGUI:
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.mioContenitore=Frame(parent)
    self.mioContenitore.pack()

    self.schermataSx=Button(self.mioContenitore)
    self.schermataSx["background"]="white"
    self.schermataSx.config(font=("helvetica",80))#vedere come ingrandire il testo senza utilizzare il button
    self.schermataSx.config(height=50, width=5)
    self.schermataSx.pack(side=LEFT)




    self.schermataDx=Label(self.mioContenitore,wraplength=450)
    self.schermataDx["background"]="white"
    self.schermataDx.config(font=("helvetica", 40)) #wraplength da rivedere
    self.schermataDx.config(height=50,width=30,anchor=W)
    self.schermataDx.pack(side=LEFT)



def cambioLett(self):
    global x
    global a
    if(GPIO.input(5)==0):
        time.sleep(1.0) # Ritardo cambio lettera da rivedere
        x+=1
    if(GPIO.input(12)==0):
        x-=1
    if(GPIO.input(7))==0: #TTS: Dice solo la prima parola
        os.system("pico2wave -l it-IT -w speak.wav "+s+" ")
        os.system("aplay speak.wav")

    if(GPIO.input(23))==0:
        os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

    if x==0:
        self.schermataSx["text"]="A"
        time.sleep(0.25)
        if(GPIO.input(17)==0):
            time.sleep(0.25)
            cont=0
            while(GPIO.input(17))==0:
                cont=cont+1
                time.sleep(0.5)
            if cont>=5:
                self.scriviSpazio()
            else:
                self.scriviLett()

        if(GPIO.input(26))==0:
            self.cancellaLett()
```

...

```
def scriviLett(self):
    global s
    global x
    if(x==0):
        s+="A"
        self.schermataDx["text"]=s
    if(x==1):
        s+="B"
        self.schermataDx["text"]=s
```

...

```
def scriviSpazio(self):
    global x
    global s
    s+=" "


def cancellaLett(self):
    global s
    s=s[:-1]
    self.schermataDx["text"]=s


root=Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
GUI=mainGUI(root)
GUI.cambioLett()
root.mainloop()
```

(I'm on Raspberry Pi).

I get this result:
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL89z.jpg)

There's the Button (left) and a label (right). I would like to mantain the size of the button but increase the text size to occupy the whole button. When i try, also the button becomes bigger. I think there's something like padding

Comment: Please post a full code, so that it is easier for us to help you out.

Comment: I've added the code that creates the right label

Comment: Is the area with "A" the button?

Comment: Yes, that's the button.

Comment: @Cosimo Sguanci Would you be able to post the entire file with include statements and functions and class? Everything please. I have only used Tkinter a couple times before so I kinda get confused if I can't see the whole structure.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: Button has `padx=` and `pady=` and you can change it to `0` (zero) but font has own margins (at the bottom for chars like `yj`, at the top for elements in native chars like `ŻŚ`) which you can't remove. If you need better result then use images with text.

Comment: I would look up the documentation for the button object. Usually you can change attributes of objects like: myButton.attributes(txtSize=20)
Attributes is probably not the term but the syntax is something like that.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Please check my answer down below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if it is even possible with tkinter. I believe your best bet would be to slap an image.

```
from tkinter import *

Tk()

background_image = PhotoImage(file='yin_yang.png')
button = Button(
    image=background_image,
    height=480,
    background='green'
)
button.pack(side=LEFT)

label = Label(
    font=('helvetica', 60),
    text='Hello, RPi :)',
)
label.pack(side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

**This is how it looks like**

[image]

Also, every time you ask a question on Stack Overflow, please try your best to refactor the code, strip it down and post a minimum but a complete code.